# Where to dump my json Sinatra

Tags: jquery, ruby, json, twitter, sinatra

Using the new twitter api (oauth) to retrieve my tweets for an app of mine. I followed [this](http://thisbythem.com/blog/simple-sinatra-for-twitter-api-pie-guy-fieri/) guide and I am dumping the JSON at the url /feed and then using an ajax call with jquery to get the data I want.

This is the plugin I'm using

```
  JQTWEET = {

// Set twitter username, number of tweets & id/class to append tweets
user: 'Davids_Carpets',
numTweets: 4,
appendTo: '#jstwitter',
// core function of jqtweet
loadTweets: function () {
    $.ajax({
            url: '/feed',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            data: {
                screen_name: JQTWEET.user,
                include_rts: false,
                count: JQTWEET.numTweets,
                include_entities: true
            },
            success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                var html = '<div class="tweet"><p class="tweetText">TWEET_TEXT</p>IMG_TAG<div class="time">AGO</div></div>';
                var img;
                // append tweets into page
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                    //this is where we grab the image, only generate the HTML code if media entities were found in the JSON data
                    try {
                        if (data[i].entities.media) {


                            img = '<a href="' + data[i].entities.media[0].media_url + '"class="showLink">View Photo';
                            img += '</a>';
                            img += '<img src="' + data[i].entities.media[0].media_url + '" class="twitterImage"  />';

                        } else {
                            img = '';
                        }
                    } catch (e) {
                        //e
                    }

                    $(JQTWEET.appendTo).append(
                        html.replace('IMG_TAG', img)

                        .replace('TWEET_TEXT', JQTWEET.ify.clean(data[i].text, img))
                        .replace(/USER/g, data[i].user.screen_name)
                        .replace('AGO', JQTWEET.timeAgo(data[i].created_at))
                        .replace(/ID/g, data[i].id_str));

                }



                $(".twitterImage").hide();

                $(".showLink").live('click', function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $(this).next(".twitterImage").show();
                    $(this).text('Hide Photo').css('display', 'block').removeClass("showLink").addClass("hideLink");

                });

                $(".hideLink").live('click', function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $(this).next(".twitterImage").hide();
                    $(this).text('View Photo').removeClass("hideLink").addClass("showLink");

                });



            }
        });

},


/**
 * relative time calculator FROM TWITTER
 * @param {string} twitter date string returned from Twitter API
 * @return {string} relative time like "2 minutes ago"
 */
timeAgo: function (dateString) {
    var rightNow = new Date();
    var then = new Date(dateString);

    /*if ($.browser.msie) {
                                            // IE can't parse these crazy Ruby dates
                                            then = Date.parse(dateString.replace(/( \+)/, ' UTC$1'));
                            }*/

    var diff = rightNow - then;

    var second = 1000,
        minute = second * 60,
        hour = minute * 60,
        day = hour * 24,
        week = day * 7;

    if (isNaN(diff) || diff < 0) {
        return ""; // return blank string if unknown
    }

    if (diff < second * 2) {
        // within 2 seconds
        return "right now";
    }

    if (diff < minute) {
        return Math.floor(diff / second) + " seconds ago";
    }

    if (diff < minute * 2) {
        return "about 1 minute ago";
    }

    if (diff < hour) {
        return Math.floor(diff / minute) + " minutes ago";
    }

    if (diff < hour * 2) {
        return "about 1 hour ago";
    }

    if (diff < day) {
        return Math.floor(diff / hour) + " hours ago";
    }

    if (diff > day && diff < day * 2) {
        return "yesterday";
    }

    if (diff < day * 365) {
        return Math.floor(diff / day) + " days ago";
    } else {
        return "over a year ago";
    }
}, // timeAgo()


/**
 * The Twitalinkahashifyer!
 * http://www.dustindiaz.com/basement/ify.html
 * Eg:
 * ify.clean('your tweet text');
 */
ify: {

    //the purpose of hasIMG parameter is to remove all the unnessary links if there is images,
    //otherwise, parse link as usual
    link: function (tweet, hasIMG) {
        return tweet.replace(/\b(((https*\:\/\/)|www\.)[^\"\']+?)(([!?,.\)]+)?(\s|$))/g, function (link, m1, m2, m3, m4) {
            var http = m2.match(/w/) ? 'http://' : '';
            if (hasIMG) return '';
            else return '<a class="twtr-hyperlink" target="_blank" href="' + http + m1 + '">' + ((m1.length > 25) ? m1.substr(0, 24) + '...' : m1) + '</a>' + m4;
        });
    },

    at: function (tweet) {
        return tweet.replace(/\B[@＠]([a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,20})/g, function (m, username) {
            return '<a target="_blank" class="twtr-atreply" href="http://twitter.com/intent/user?screen_name=' + username + '">@' + username + '</a>';
        });
    },

    list: function (tweet) {
        return tweet.replace(/\B[@＠]([a-zA-Z0-9_]{1,20}\/\w+)/g, function (m, userlist) {
            return '<a target="_blank" class="twtr-atreply" href="http://twitter.com/' + userlist + '">@' + userlist + '</a>';
        });
    },

    hash: function (tweet) {
        return tweet.replace(/(^|\s+)#(\w+)/gi, function (m, before, hash) {
            return before + '<a target="_blank" class="twtr-hashtag" href="http://twitter.com/search?q=%23' + hash + '">#' + hash + '</a>';
        });
    },

    //added hasIMG parameter
    clean: function (tweet, hasIMG) {
        return this.hash(this.at(this.list(this.link(tweet, hasIMG))));
    }
} // ify

};



// start jqtweet!
JQTWEET.loadTweets();
```

app.rb

```
get '/feed' do
  jsonp twitter_client.user_timeline('twitter handle', :count => 4).map(&:attrs)
end
```

Im thinking this is a bad practice and am interested to find out how I can refactor this to be more efficient/ follow best practices. Is there a better way to store the response

Any help appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to use the official Twitter API gem? What is the trouble you are facing with this code?

Comment: its the fact that the JSON is returned to the url /feed, so if a user ever visited /feed they would see the JSON returned, I was wondering if there was a better way to store the JSON (other than saving to a model)